# Issue with views using Areas

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am about to pull my hair out!!
So I have areas setup in my MVC 3 project, I have an AccountController and Model as well as a view

When you add an area VS sets up the structure for you and I have not modified that. With all of that said, my views are not working. The controller works, when I set a breakpoint I see

```
// **************************************
// URL: /Account/LogOn
// **************************************

public ActionResult LogOn()
{
    return View();
}
```

It is getting hit however I get the YPOD(Yellow page of Death) when returning the view. I have tried a view with partial rendering as well as the LogOn.cshtml, partial being located in the shared folder for the area and the non partial in the Views/Account folder.

Is this just broken or am I missing something?

Comment: What is *not working*? Saying that something is not working is like saying nothing. You said you were getting a YSOD. Any relevant information this YSOD contained such as exception text you would like to share with us? Or you probably expect us reading your YSODs with crystal magic balls?

Comment: It is not searching the areas for the views The view 'LogOn' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched:
~/Views/Account/LogOn.aspx
~/Views/Account/LogOn.ascx
~/Views/Shared/LogOn.aspx
~/Views/Shared/LogOn.ascx
~/Views/Account/LogOn.cshtml
~/Views/Account/LogOn.vbhtml
~/Views/Shared/LogOn.cshtml
~/Views/Shared/LogOn.vbhtml

Comment: @Anoddperson Iam, how does your request url look like in the browser?

Comment: http://testsite/Account/Account/Logon On a side note, I am not happy with the URL, i tried mapping a route for /Account/Logon and even /Logon. The view is still not found. However breakpoint gets hit on the ActionResult

Comment: So why is it not searching the areas?? is the AreaRegistration class not working??

Comment: @Anoddperson Iam, I am unable to reproduce your scenario. I've created a new ASP.NET MVC 3 project, added an Area using Visual Studio Wizard, added a controller and a view: worked perfectly fine. No idea what your problem is. Hopefully someone will reproduce your scenario and be able to answer the question.

Comment: I have added the following and still no joy! routes.MapRoute(
                 "Logon", // Route name
                 "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                 new { area="Account", controller = "Account", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
             );

Comment: I was missing a controller="Account" in my area registration. It now works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing a controller="Account" in my area registration. It now works:

```
public class AccountAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration
{
    public override string AreaName
    {
        get
        {
            return "Account";
        }
    }

    public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
    {
        context.MapRoute(
            "Account_default",
            "Account/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { area = "Account", controller = "Account", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```